# Can't call an alert inside a function in ionic 4

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, firebase-authentication, ionic-native, ionic4

I wan't to call an alert inside a function which is implementing Firebase authentication.

**My Typescript code (jQuery Enabled)**:

```
async emptyAlert() {
    const empty = await this.alertController.create({
      header: 'Error!',
      message: 'All fields are required. Please fill the details and try again',
      buttons: ['OK']
    });

    await empty.present();
  }
async errorAlert(message) {
    const errorAl = await this.alertController.create({
      header: 'Error!',
      message: message,
      buttons: ['OK']
    });
    await errorAl.present();
  }

  doLogin() {
    const email = $('#loginEmail').val();
    const password = $('#loginPassword').val();
    if (email === '' || password === '') {
      this.emptyAlert();
    } else {
      firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).catch(function(error) {
        // Handle Errors here.
        // const errorCode = error.code;
        const errorMessage = error.message;
        this.errorAlert(errorMessage);
      });
    }
  }
```

Please note that the above code is implemented after `constructor(public alertController: AlertController) { }` present inside `export class LoginPage implements OnInit{…}`

I am able to call emptyAlert(), which is a similar alert like errorAlert, but when I call errorAlert(), it says **ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'errorAlert' of undefined**.

Please help. *Thanks in advance.*

Comment: @KumarPriyanash Please close your question by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer that helped you most.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use **[`arrow function`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)**, this is automatically bound correctly.you can transpile the arrow functions if you plan on supporting browsers

```
firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).catch((error) => {
        // Handle Errors here.
        // const errorCode = error.code;
        const errorMessage = error.message;
        this.errorAlert(errorMessage);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi try to substitute your callback function with arrow function like:

```
firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).catch((error) => {
        // Handle Errors here.
        // const errorCode = error.code;
        const errorMessage = error.message;
        this.errorAlert(errorMessage);
      });
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `function(error) {}`, `this` represent new scope.

you should use `() => {}` so it is in same scope.

```
firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).catch((error) => {
  // Handle Errors here.
  // const errorCode = error.code;
  const errorMessage = error.message;
  this.errorAlert(errorMessage);
});
```